# How to delete part of a string in C++

Tags: c++, string, operators

I would like to know if there is a way to delete part of a string in c++ and save the remaining part in a variable.

`com` is an input from the user, (example: `Write myfile`)

I want to delete `Write` from this input to obtain only (`myfile`) to use as name for a file to be created. `Write` variable contains the string  (`Write`). `Com` is the input and `names` is the variable in which to save the name of the file.

```
write.names = com - write.Writevariable;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>           // std::cout & std::cin
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  string str ("This is an example phrase.");
  string::iterator it;

  str.erase (10,8);
  cout << str << endl;        // "This is an phrase."

  it=str.begin()+9;
  str.erase (it);
  cout << str << endl;        // "This is a phrase."

  str.erase (str.begin()+5, str.end()-7);
  cout << str << endl;        // "This phrase."
  return 0;
}
```

you can get the position and delete a string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [string::erase()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase) method

Answer (score 0):

Use [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) to delete part of string.

```
std::string names = com.substr( write.length() );
```

As mentioned in other answers, you can also use `std::string::erase`, but it will require an extra copy in other variable. Usage:

```
std::string names(com);
names.erase(0, write.length());
```